# how to hide the warnings from method READ-XML()

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

When I read data into a dataset with the method hDataset:READ-XML() and the path to the file is incorrect, Progress first shows a warning message (warning nr 4065) and then an error message. I can catch (using a CATCH block) the error message, but not the warning. The user must remove the warning manually.

How can I suppress this warning?

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO
    FIELD a AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE DATASET ds FOR tt.

DO ON ERROR UNDO , LEAVE:
    /* Reading non existing xml-file */
    DATASET ds:READ-XML("FILE", "c:\dddw\s.xml","empty","", FALSE, "","" ).

    CATCH err AS Progress.Lang.Error :
         MESSAGE err:GETMESSAGE(1)
            VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
    END CATCH.

END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generelly in Progress ABL you supress messages with adding `NO-ERROR` after the command/method.

```
hDataset:READ-XML() NO-ERROR.
```

After that you would normally check if `ERROR-STATUS:STATUS = TRUE` (an error occured), however that doesn's seem to work in this case.

This examples work:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO
    FIELD a AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE DATASET ds FOR tt.

DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
/* Reading non existing xml-file */
DATASET ds:READ-XML("FILE", "c:\dddw\s.xml","empty","", FALSE, "","" ) NO-ERROR.
/* This is false */
DISP ERROR-STATUS:ERROR.

/* However, ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES shows 2 errors */
IF ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES > 0 THEN DO:
    DO i = 1 TO ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES:
        DISPLAY ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(i) FORMAT "x(66)".
        PAUSE.
    END.
END.
```

If the file you want to read is local you can (should?) do `SEARCH(path+file)` first - that will return ? if the file doesn't exist.

```
IF SEARCH("/mydir/myfile.xml") = ? THEN DO:
  MESSAGE "The file seems to be lost" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
  RETURN.
END.
ELSE DO:
  /* Read XML etc */
END.
```

Comment: thanks for answer. it works. i forget the old 4GL handling. 
generally should progress catch the warnings too... else It does not make sense...